# How to get the timestamp (and location stamp) with a keypress?

Tags: windows, windows-8, timestamp

I need this info in many places:

```
Date     Time Lat   Long
20130223 0800 44.44 32.33
```

Most of the time, I key in the date and time manually or using a program shortcut key like <kbd>F5</kbd> in Notepad.

But, I need this at many places, and I don't want to always type / use the program's built-in copy-paste function. I need to just press a key on the keyboard – or two keys, say <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> and I need the data.

Is there any direct way to do that? Or any combination of tools?

Comment: Is there a particular program you're trying to accomplish this in?

Comment: No.  I want to use it when naming files, or within text files, or within excel.

Comment: I think http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm does help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autohotkey is a great tool for Windows that is great for tying text insertion to universal hotkeys.  It's scripting language has built in functionality for filling in date and time. They have a [page with details and examples](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm) of how to specify custom date/time formatting. There are also many [tutorials and examples](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) that can help you get started as well as lots of ready-made user scripts available around the web.

Answer (score 0):

[PhaseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) is user friendly, and free.

Comment: Can you expand on why it might be helpful in your answer?